# Is wait still necessary for non-blocking send with blocking receive

Tags: mpi, communication, distributed-computing

I knew if both sides are non-blocking send and receive, then a `MPI_Wait` or `MPI_Test` is required. But I wondered If we mix non-blocking send and blocking receive, do I still need to call `MPI_Wait` considering that blocking receive can ensure the completion of the communication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between non-blocking and blocking communication mode is only locally. You may freely mix different kinds of send and receive. On whichever side you use non-blocking primitives, you **must always issue an `MPI_Wait` or something similar** to complete the communication.

This is necessary to clean up resources: If you never complete a non-blocking send, you would never be allowed to reuse the send buffer and accumulate lingering request objects.

Comment: note most MPI implementations do not have a progress thread. from a very pragmatic point of view, `MPI_Isend()` of a large message will not transfer anything until `MPI_{Recv,Wait,Test,Probe}()` and friends are called.

Comment: valid point. I didn't want to go into the details of progress guarantee - the way I remember it's more complicated than just the direci completion functions.